# moving UINavigationBar frame causes unrecognizable clicks

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uigesturerecognizer

Iam using uinavigationController in my app , when I click on the left key the app must show a side menu (which moves the main view and the navigation bar to the right ) , the views clicks which is under the navigation bar (when I move it's frame) doesn't trigger any thing
[image]

for example the up red label .
at the upper half it doesn't recognize clicks , but the other half does recognize clicks .
how can I solve that ?